# Story about a boy and girl who get powers from a magical field

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, childrens-novel

I remember a story from when I was a kid about a boy and a girl who got powers and then lost them. I’ll try to tell you what I remember, and hopefully somebody will know what I’m talking about and where I can find this story:

From what I can remember there was a magical field that the boy discovered with a tree in it and a rock. He gains the ability to do anything he can think of, including flight. His female friend then finds the field too, and I remember them having a discussion about their powers. He demonstrates that he can fly around the tree. He was excited someone else knew the secret, and she told him she had gotten powers too, by saying something to the effect of, “it’s not that I can *do* anything, it’s that I *know* everything.”

She then proceeds to tell him that, for instance, if she tilts her head to a certain angle she knows that buried 6 inches under the ground near them is a coin or something. The boy digs and does in fact find what she had described. They agree that they must never tell anyone about their powers or they will lose their new abilities altogether.

Later the boy is injured somehow,I believe he broke his arm, and the girl knew how to bandage him up and drive him to a hospital because of her abilities, but then when she got there the adults were suspicious of how a child could have done all that. I believe in the end they both lose their powers.

Does any of this sound at all familiar to someone?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It would help us if we knew about what year you're talking about, since we don't know when you were a kid.  You've also tagged this as both a children's novel and a short story; is it a novel or a short?